# Is ScrollableTabRow lazy

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

If i create like 1000 Tabs within the ScrollableTabRow will it only compose the Tabs which are visible to the screen or`will compose everytime non-visible Tabs if something changes?

Like same as a LazyColumn composes only visible items.

Comment: No the lazy stuff is marked `Lazy` for clarity

Comment: I mean pre-fixed

Answer (score 1):

I've written a minimal example in which i'm just "repeat"ing the same composable a lot of times - with no `item{}`-like DSL available like the lazy-components have.

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun MinimalTabExample() {
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    ScrollableTabRow(selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex) {
        repeat(60) { tabNumber ->
            Tab(
                selected = selectedTabIndex == tabNumber,
                onClick = { selectedTabIndex = tabNumber },
                text = { Text(text = "Tab #$tabNumber") }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you look into the `ScrollableTabRow` component you'll find that all the tabs are measured right at the beginning: (`tabs` are the compose-tabs created above)

```
val tabPlaceables = subcompose(TabSlots.Tabs, tabs)
                .map { it.measure(tabConstraints) }
```

I guess this is implemented this way due to the height-calculation: "Make the height as high as the highest component"

```
tabPlaceables.forEach {
    layoutWidth += it.width
    layoutHeight = maxOf(layoutHeight, it.height)
}
```